# TransientObjectException while trying to update whole object

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am checking if an object is already present in the db & then updating the whole object if it's present or create new if not. However while in application launch I'm getting the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.model.Students
```

I looked it up online but more answers were related to relational mappings but my table has no relationship with any other tables. I don't know what to do. Please help.

here is my model:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_student")
public class Students extends People {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.Auto)
    @Column(name="id",insertable =false,nullable = false,updatable = false)
    private Long id;
    
    private int rollNo;

    private String address;

    private String email;

    @Convert(converter = StringListConverter.class)
    private List<String> subjects;

}
```

People class:

```
@Data
@MappedSuperclass
public class People  {

    private int age;
    private String name;
    private String hobbies;
    private String country;

}
```

My repo:

```
public interface StudentsRepository extends JpaRepository<Students,Long> {

    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query("update Students s set s = :updatedStudent WHERE s.name = :name")
    void updateStudent(@Param("name") String name, @Param(updatedStudent) Students updatedStudent);

Optional<Students> findByName(String name);

}
```

This is what I'm doing:

```
 if(studentsRepository.findByName(value.getName()).isPresent())
                        {
                            studentsRepository.updatestudents(value.getName(),value);
                        }else {
                            studentsRepository.saveAndFlush(value);

                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the source code that is throwing the exception correctly, it's not the `Students` class that is having the transient reference, it IS the reference.

This means you are probably also saving something else wich is referencing a `Students` instance, which needs saving.